# wine: can't connect to server

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, wine

Some of the applications I installed through wine need to connect to the internet, but it appears they're not able to. They produce the following error on such an attempt:

```
Can't connect to server
```

How do I enable internet access for these applications?

I am running Pangolin, 64 bit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specific Wine Applications don't have Internet Access](http://askubuntu.com/questions/657081/specific-wine-applications-dont-have-internet-access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A friend of mine](http://0branch.com/) helped me solve the issue.

Download the latest version of PlayOnLinux, then from within it, get wine version 1.4, and install Evernote on a new virtual drive using this exact version of wine. Then it would work.

Comment: Do you have an idea why this works ? Wine is now in version 1.7..

Answer (score 2):

Installing lib32nss-mdns should help you to resolve the issue

Open terminal and try `sudo apt-get install lib32nss-mdns`

Comment: Thank you for your input. Already tried that (because that's what the first suggestion on google said too), followed by a reboot. It didn't solve the problem for me.

Comment: Are you trying to open any SSL connections or just normal connection?

Comment: I am trying to use Evernote. I don't know what sort of connection it attempts to make.

Comment: Evernote uses SSL connection. Then the problem is with your wine installation. The wine package that come with 12.04 uses libssl1.0.0. Try using the older version of [libssl](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/libssl0.9.8/0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.1)

Comment: Will it help if I install wine 1.5? I am currently using 1.4.