# Specific Wine Applications don't have Internet Access

Tags: wine, 15.04, evernote

I installed Wine and tried to install Evernote with it. I got an old install file of Evernote (5.6.4.4632) because this version worked under Ubuntu 14.04. I'm now using Ubuntu 15.04.

When I launch Evernote, an error message pops up, telling me that it can't connect to the server.

So I downloaded Firefox for Windows, installed it using Wine and it has internet access.

I also tried cleaning out my Wine prefix and using a newer version of Evernote (5.8.13.8152) in case the server doesn't accept the old one any longer.

[ I'm aware of the fact that there are alternative clients but I prefer the original application for various reasons. ]

Comment: Same problem here...  Evernote_5.8.1.6061 working in 14.10 until 15.04 upgrade, Evernote_5.8.13.8152 can't conect too. I've Wine 1.7.44... But in https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=31491&iTestingId=89253 it's reported as working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a solution suggested in this post: [How to configure wine to install Evernote?](https://askubuntu.com/a/575821/299538), explained further here: [instalar-evernote-en-linux](http://blog.desdelinux.net/instalar-evernote-en-linux/) (is in Spanish but it has a lot of images)

You could install [playonlinux](http://apt://playonlinux). Once PlayOnLinux is installed, goto *manage wine versions*, and install wine 1.4.1 32bit.

Then click *install program* -> *install a non-listed program* -> *Install a program in a new virtual drive*.

Give a name for your application virtual drive ("evernote" or whatever you like), then mark *Use another version of wine* and select the 1.4.1 that you've just installed. Kind of virtual drive I choose *32bit windows installation*.

Browse for the installer in your drive, wait for the installation to finish and close Evernote, so PlayOnLinux can notice that the installation has finished.

This works for Evernote_5.8.13.8152 in Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Thank you! I read the Wine 1.4.1 thing and tried to install Evernote via playonlinux but didn't choose "use another version of wine" since I assumed it would use the only one I previously installed if I don't choose a different version. However, it used the system version. It works now.

Comment: You're welcome, now I'm using wine 1.7.35 and it works too, it didn't with 1.7.44... I also had a problem with note tittles and text in search field, and it solved installing `riched20` in *install components*

Comment: So basically the problem happens with some very specific Wine versions and works fine with some other very specific versions ? I have the very same problem with another application.

Comment: Yes, that was the case with evernote.

Comment: I just wanted to post an update to this and say I got evernote version 5.8.5.7193 working with wine 1.7.35 on Ubuntu 15.04. I had to try several version to get it working.

Comment: Is curious that a newer version of evernote haven't worked for you. I'm still using 5.8.13.8152.

Answer (score 4):

You need the 32 bit dns resolution libraries.
To install this library, run one of the following commands as root:

```
64-bit Debian 8 : apt-get install libnss-mdns:i386
32-bit Debian or Ubuntu : apt-get install libnss-mdns
64-bit Ubuntu : apt-get install libnss-mdns:i386
32/64-bit Fedora : dnf install nss-mdns.i686
32-bit Mandriva : urpmi nss_mdns
64-bit Mandriva : Not available
32-bit SUSE : zypper install nss-mdns
64-bit SUSE : zypper install nss-mdns-32bit
32-bit Arch : pacman -Syu nss-mdns
64-bit Debian 7 and older : apt-get install lib32nss-mdns
```

Nothing but wine needs 32 bit binaries as it is mentioned here: https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Why_doesn.27t_DNS_resolve_in_64-bit_operating_systems.3F